# Product of Ciruclant Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been working on this, but I can't seem to make any progress.

Show that that for circulant matrices $A$ and $B$, $AB = BA$.

I tried finding a some special property about these ciruclant matrices that I could expoit, but I haven't been able to find anything.

Comment: The definition of a ciruclant matrix is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix.

Answer (score 2):

An $n \times n$ circulant matrix can be written as a linear combination of $I$, $P$, $P^2$,... $P^{n-1}$, where $P$ is a permutation matrix.  The individual powers commute, so linear combinations of them commute.

Comment: What is the form of the permutation matrix used to create a circular matrix?

Comment: $1$ in the top right corner and the first sub-diagonal, $0$'s elsewhere.